# Error setting up a Perfect server on Ubuntu using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ubuntu, perfect

Im trying to use Swift as a backend by installing it on an Ubuntu Server. I followed these instructions:
http://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-swift-with-perfect/
Unfortunately when I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect.git
cd Perfect/PerfectLib
make
sudo make install
```

I get an error when running "make". The error is as follows:

```
<module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#include "curl_support.hpp"
         ^
/home/chris/Perfect/PerfectLib/linked/cURL_Linux/curl_support.hpp:30:10:
error: 'curl/curl.h' file not found
#include "curl/curl.h"
         ^
cURL.swift:26:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'cURL'
import cURL
```

i tried with all the different Swift Snapshots here:
https://swift.org/download/#apple-platforms
but still nothing. 
Please can anyone help? Im using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Check out Vapor. https://github.com/qutheory/vapor
It's tested on Ubuntu 14.04, 15.10 and OS X

Answer (score 4):

You need to install curl library in order to have it on your system :)

`sudo apt-get install curl` should solve your problem.

I personally use this vagrantfile, that sets up my Virtual Machine (so I don't mess up my regular linux settings by mistake)

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  ## 1 get the ubuntu image
  config.vm.box = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    ## 2 Install all necessary dependencies
    sudo apt-get --assume-yes install clang libssl-dev libevent-dev libsqlite3-dev libicu-dev uuid-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev git

    ## 3 get the swift snapshot
    curl -O https://swift.org/builds/ubuntu1404/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz

    ## 4 unpack
    tar zxf swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz

    ## 5 add swift snapshot to PATH
    echo "export PATH=/home/vagrant/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin:\"${PATH}\"" >> .profile
    echo "Swift has successfully installed on Linux"

    ## 5.5 create tiny script that will install all the Perfect Libs and have them accessible for the non-sudo user
    echo "git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect.git
    cd Perfect/PerfectLib
    make
    sudo make install
    cd ../PerfectServer
    make" >> compilePerfectLib.sh
    chmod a+x compilePerfectLib.sh
    echo "Remember to run ./compilePerfectLib.sh after logging into the VM"
  SHELL

  config.vm.network :public_network #, bridge: "wlan0"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8181, host: 8181
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 300 
end
```

Then after you do `vagrant ssh` and you're logged in the VM (Virtual Machine), you need to `sh ./compilePerfectLib.sh` and that will setup your environment :)

Good luck!